# Strange null reference exceptions in a function I wrote

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, xmpp, nullreferenceexception

```
private void GoogleTalkClient_OnMessage(object sender, jabber.protocol.client.Message msg)
    {
        connectionsNumber.Maximum = rosterManager.Count;
        if (session.Keys.Contains<string>(msg.From.Bare)){

            session.TryGetValue(msg.From.Bare,out thissession);

        }else{
            if (cleverbot.Keys.Contains<string>(msg.From.Bare)){
                cleverbot.TryGetValue(msg.From.Bare,out bot);
            }else{
                bot = factory.Create(ChatterBotType.CLEVERBOT);
                if (bot != null)
                cleverbot.Add(msg.From.Bare, bot);
            }
            thissession = bot.CreateSession();
            if (thissession != null)
            session.Add(msg.From.Bare, thissession);
        }
        connectionsNumber.Value = session.Count;
        jabber.protocol.client.Message reply = new jabber.protocol.client.Message(GoogleTalkClient.Document);
        reply.Body = thissession.Think(Grammarcheck(msg.Body));
        reply.To = msg.From;
        GoogleTalkClient.Write(reply);
    }
```

the code is C# and it is giving me nullreference errors on all of the session.Add() and cleverbot.Add() statements and i can't figure out why (cleverbot and session are dictionarys)

Comment: either you forgot to initialize `cleverbot` and `session`, or the data you're passing in is null. Step through the code with the debugger to see which it is.

Comment: Did you properly initialize the dictionaries? One cannot say much about a possible solution only judging by that piece of code.

Comment: You must initialize them with `Dictionary<string,Session> session = new Dictionary<string,Session>();` and `Dictionary<string,CleverBot> clerverbot = new Dictionary<string,CleverBot>();`. This `Dictionary<string,Session> session;` alone does not create a dictionary and it will be null.

Comment: yes,  the data is not null, I checked with the debugger.

Comment: Then the key is null (`msg.From.Bare == null`) or `msg` is null or `msg.From` is null.

Comment: no it was not initialized for some reason...

Comment: oh... if anyone wants to see what this working try inviting cleverbot.gtalk@gmail.com to chat and then chatting with it.

Comment: You should use `ContainsKey()` instead of `Keys.Contains()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dictionaries were not properly initialized